# Why we need Transient Fault Handling for storage?

Tags: azure

I saw some thread said storage library already have retry policy, 
So why should us use this :[Transient Fault Handling block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680905%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)

Can any one show me some samples about how to use this Transient Fault handling block for myy blob and Table storage properly? 
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For implementation examples, read on in the link you sent - the Key Scenarios section.  If you aren't having problems connecting, then don't implement.  We use it, but it hasn't helped as far as we know.  Every fault we've encountered has been a longer term, Azure internal network related issue that caused faults the TFHB couldn't handle.

Answer (score 1):

One reason (and the reason I use it in my application) is that the transient fault handling application block provides retry logic for not only storage (tables, blobs and queues) but also for SQL Azure as well as Service Bus Queues. If your project makes use of these additional resources (namely SQL Azure and Service Bus Queues) and you would want to have a single library to handle transient faults, I would recommend using this over storage client library.

Another reason I would give for using this library is it's extensibility. You could probably extend this library to handle other error scenarios (not covered by storage client library retry policies) or use it against other web resources like service management API.

If you're just using blob and table storage, you could very well use the retry policies which come with storage client library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the Transient Fault Handling block for blob storage, it may be more applicable to table storage or when transmitting larger chunks of data. Given that I use blob storage containers to archive debug information (in the form of short txt files) on certain areas of the site, it seems a little convoluted. I've never once witnessed any failures writing to storage and we write 10s of thousands of logs a week. Of course different usage of storage may  yield different reliability.

Answer (score 0):

For tables and blobs you do not need to use any external transient retry blocks afaik. The ones that are implemented within the sdk are fairly robust. If you think you should implement a special retry policy the way to do that is to implement your own retry policy inheriting from Azure Storage `IRetryPolicy` interface and pass that on to your storage requests as part of the `TableRequestOptions.RetryPolicy` property.