# Is it advisable to use the PandP Transient Error Handling Block with AZMS?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Can the Pattern and Practices Transient Error Handling Block be used with AZMS?  Is it necessary given the retry logic already built into AZMS?

Comment: You should probably be clearer on if you mean Azure Mobile Services or Azure Media Services.

Answer (score 0):

The transient fault handling block can be use with just about anything, however, some people look at the home page and think it doesn't support something because it's not listed on the page.  It comes with handlers that understand the various transient faults that the Service Bus, SQL Database and Storage can produce, but that doesn't mean it is limited to those services.  The block is extensible so that if you implement your own [ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680940%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) you can get it to retry for just about any service.  The trick is knowing how to identify the exceptions that are good to retry.

Gaurav Mantri provided a good answer on a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16357201/614809) saying that if you just are dealing with one service that has retry logic built in then the Transient Fault block isn't as attractive, but if you are working with many types of services then having a consistent way of handling these is a good idea.